# Brother MFC-J470DW scan function "Check Connection"

Tags: 14.04, scanner, brother

I have a Brother MFC-J470DW printer that I have connected to a 
Linux desktop (running Ubuntu 14.04) using a wireless router
network.  The printer works fine for printing and copying, but 
now I want to add the scan function.

To set up the scan function, I went to the Brother web page [Downloads](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcj470dw_us_eu_as&os=128)
for this printer:

and under Scanner Drivers selected "Scanner driver 64bit
(deb package)", "Scan-key-tool 64bit (deb package)", and
"Scanner Setting file (deb package)".   For each package, I
accepted the EULA, and selected "open with Ubuntu Software
Center".  Then after the USC window pops up, I click on
Install and the red line goes from left to right.   In each
case, the USC window then had a green check mark and the
Install box changes to Reinstall (that's how you know it
worked).

So now I try it out.  Hitting the Scan button on the
printer, selecting "Scan to file", and hitting OK produces
the message **"Check Connection"**.

I checked the Brother Linux Information FAQ (scanner) page
and the 14th question seems the same as mine:

```
    When I try to use the scan key on my network connected
    machine, I receive the error "Check connection" or I can not
    select anything except "scan to FTP".
```

I explored the solution given for this FAQ, but found from
`ifconfig` that I am already using `eth0`, the default setting,
so presumably that is not the problem.

I also found `brscan-skey` installed in `/usr/bin` and did

```
drrm@drrmlinux2:~$ brscan-skey -t
drrm@drrmlinux2:~$ brscan-skey
```

but that didn't help - I still get the "Check connection" message.

What can you suggest to fix this problem?

---

Brother released an upgrade for scan driver dated 05/06/2014.  I installed, but still get the "Check Connection" message.  On the downloads page (deb version), they also still state the release date as 12/03/2014 for the scan-key-tool 64-bit and scanner settings file packages, which has not changed.  So maybe I just have to wait some months to see if the release date of these other packages changes.

Comment: As a first-time user of askubuntu, I am completely confused.  I asked a question, got a proposed solution yesterday, which now seems to have disappeared, and added a comment that the proposed solution did not work, which has also disappeared.  I have no idea of what to do.

Comment: Scanning in Ubuntu does not work like that with the press of a button in the printer. Open the application Simple Scan in Ubuntu and use it to scan the document.

Comment: These low-end Brother printers don't allow scan to email directly. They rely on running applications on pc or phones to receive scanned files and (maybe) attach them to emails after launching the default mail application. What's baffling is that the web interface let you configure the SMTP server until the very last step (including auth verification step), but the scan key can't be configured to send an email directly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my scanning issue by typing in ﻿View Local Services﻿, find ﻿Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)﻿, click on ﻿Log On﻿, set ﻿Long on as: ﻿to ﻿Local System account﻿ with ﻿Allow service to interact with desktop﻿ checked, click ﻿OK﻿.